# Insert rows in pandas where one column misses some value in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my dataframe:

```
user1    user2    cat    quantity + other quantities
----------------------------------------------------
Alice    Bob      0      ....
Alice    Bob      1      ....
Alice    Bob      2      ....
Alice    Carol    0      ....
Alice    Carol    2      ....
```

I want to make sure that every `user1-user2` pair has a row corresponding to each category (there are three: 0,1,2). If not, I want to insert a row, and set the other columns to zero.

```
user1    user2    cat    quantity + other quantities
----------------------------------------------------
Alice    Bob      0      ....
Alice    Bob      1      ....
Alice    Bob      2      ....
Alice    Carol    0      ....
Alice    Carol    1      <SET ALL TO ZERO>
Alice    Carol    2      ....
```

what I have so far is the list of all `user1-user2` which has less than 3 values for `cat`:

```
df.groupby(['user1','user2']).agg({'cat':'count'}).reset_index()[['user1','user2']]
```

I could iterate over these users, but that will take a long time (there are >1M such pairs). I've checked at other solutions for inserting rows in pandas based on some condition (like [Pandas/Python adding row based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091963/pandas-python-adding-row-based-on-condition) and [Insert row in Pandas Dataframe based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573448/insert-row-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-condition)) but they're not exactly the same.

Also, since this is a huge dataset, the solution has to be vectorized. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
print (df)
   user1  user2  cat  quantity  a
0  Alice    Bob    0         2  4
1  Alice    Bob    1         3  4
2  Alice    Bob    2         4  4
3  Alice  Carol    0         6  4
4  Alice  Carol    2         3  4

df = df.set_index(['user1','user2', 'cat'])
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names) 
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
   user1  user2  cat  quantity  a
0  Alice    Bob    0         2  4
1  Alice    Bob    1         3  4
2  Alice    Bob    2         4  4
3  Alice  Carol    0         6  4
4  Alice  Carol    1         0  0
5  Alice  Carol    2         3  4
```

Another solution is create new `Dataframe` by all combinations of unique values of columns and `merge` with `right` join:

```
from  itertools import product

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['user1'].unique(),
                                df['user2'].unique(),
                                df['cat'].unique())), columns=['user1','user2', 'cat'])
df = df.merge(df1, how='right').fillna(0)
print (df)
   user1  user2  cat  quantity    a
0  Alice    Bob    0       2.0  4.0
1  Alice    Bob    1       3.0  4.0
2  Alice    Bob    2       4.0  4.0
3  Alice  Carol    0       6.0  4.0
4  Alice  Carol    2       3.0  4.0
5  Alice  Carol    1       0.0  0.0
```

EDIT2:

```
df['user1'] = df['user1'] + '_' + df['user2']
df = df.set_index(['user1', 'cat']).drop('user2', 1)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df[['user1','user2']] = df['user1'].str.split('_', expand=True)
print (df)
   user1  cat  quantity  a  user2
0  Alice    0         2  4    Bob
1  Alice    1         3  4    Bob
2  Alice    2         4  4    Bob
3  Alice    0         6  4  Carol
4  Alice    1         0  0  Carol
5  Alice    2         3  4  Carol
```

EDIT3:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['user1','user2'])
df = (df.groupby(['user1','user2'])[cols]
        .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('cat').reindex(df['cat'].unique(), fill_value=0))
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   user1  user2  cat  a  quantity
0  Alice    Bob    0  4         2
1  Alice    Bob    1  4         3
2  Alice    Bob    2  4         4
3  Alice  Carol    0  4         6
4  Alice  Carol    1  0         0
5  Alice  Carol    2  4         3
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, thanks. But I get a Memory Error at the `MultiIndex.from_product` step. There are 1.2 M pairs, so that could be the issue.

Comment: New colution was added, can you check it?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I checked it too, it uses too much memory. I don't think I can do with a product since the products are very large. I actually need this for creating histograms (I need to include all user pairs for each cat, but they get omitted by groupby if they're not there). Since products seem impossible, I'm thinking maybe I could add the zeros in `arr` in `ax.hist(arr)` instead of in the dataframe itself.

Comment: @irene - One idea - if both columns are joined together, still same problem? Check EDIT2.

Comment: @irene - And I found another idea - `groupby` + `reindex`, `EDIT3`

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I'm trying out EDIT3. The good news is the memory is in check -- but it seems to be taking a lot of time. I'll keep it running though and post back what happens when it's done.

Comment: yes, this was reason for not use groupby in first solutions - too slow. but I think you get what you want. :)

Comment: I'll also try EDIT2 if I lose patience with EDIT3 haha. We'll see about the memory though.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's the set_index step in EDIT3 that takes a lot of time.

Comment: hmmm, there is main problem pandas working nice with large data, BUT need a lot of memory :(